# Getting a list of file associations

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a program that is supposed to save reports in different file formats, and if there is an application associated with the file extension, then open that file using that application.

Is is possible to get all file extensions that have applications associated with them in windows?

I tried the registry entry HK_CLASSES_ROOT{extension}, but i looked at a base windows xp ( without office), and it still has keys for all kinds of extensions..

---

I would need to know if there is any associattion before attempting to open the file, also if the association doesnt exist, then i need to open the folder in windows explorer where the file resides ...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to get the associated application. You can simply use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("fileName.xyz");
```

to open a file with the associated application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the ASSOC command on the command-line.  It may give you the information that you need.  (Try 'assoc /?', or just run 'assoc' in a shell.)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/System_File_Association.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell you can list all file extension in from registry at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

```
#============================================================================================================================================================ 
# AUTHOR:         metadataconsult@gmail.com 
# WEBSITE:        http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.com 
# 
# SCRIPT NAME:    GetAllFileExtensions.ps1   
# DATE:           17/10/2018  
# VERSION:        1.0.0.0
# 
# SYNPOSIS:       Get all file extensions from registry at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT  
#
#============================================================================================================================================================ 

#set HKCR hack
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
$i=0
Get-ChildItem 'HKCR:\' | ForEach-Object {  

 If($_.name -Match "^HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\\..+") {
    $i++
    Write-Host  $_.Name.Replace("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\","")
 }

}
"$i file extensions in Registry @ HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\"
```